# Minimal degree of $A_{n}$ irreducible representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

I'm looking for a proof of the fact that, if you call $m_n$ the minimal degree of non-trivial irreducible representation of the alternating group $A_n,$ the sequence $\{m_n\}$ tends to $\infty$ for $n \to \infty.$

I have quite basic notions about representation theory (for example, I don't know anything about representations of $S_n$), but I was told that this problem is solvable with elementary notions.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure if this is an easier way to see it, but it suffices to show that the same is true for the minimal $m$ such that $GL_m$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $A_n$.

Comment: If you know that irreducible (complex) representations of abelian groups have dimension $1$, then it follows that an abelian group with a faithful representation of degree $n$ can be generated by at most $n$ elements . But $A_n$ has abelian subgroups of exponent $2$ that need $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1$ generators.